# How to specify Nuget Package Id with Asp.net 5 (dnu pack)

Tags: c#, nuget, asp.net-core

Is it possible to specify a setting in the `project.json` file that will make the  `dnu pack` command produce a NuGet package with a different name than the name of the project that was packed?

Basically we had to shorten our project names for publishing reasons and would like to make the package names be the fully qualified namespace.

I believe this is the equivalent of setting the Id field in a `.nuspec`.

Comment: So did you try changing the `id` node to the name you want?

Comment: I can, but I'd rather it be more automated than that. I'd either have to write something custom to do that after the package is produced or do it manually each time before publishing. I'm just surprised that the only option would be to use the project name and not be able to overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs` file, you can override some of the properties in the `.nuspec`, which will actually force it to import tokens from `AssemblyInfo.cs` instead.

In this case, you're interested in the `AssemblyTitle` CLR attribute:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("ShortPackageName")]
...
```

Then after you generate your .nuspec, it should look like this with a placeholder:

```
<metadata>
  <id>$id$</id>
```

**EDIT**:

Okay, it looks like `dnu pack` ignores `.nuspec` and reads from `project.json` instead. 
In that file, add this:

```
"description": "ShortPackageName",
```

Comment: I don't think that helps since it appears ASP.NET 5 'dnu pack' doesn't honor the nuspec file as far as I can tell. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: What's the difference between `nuget pack` and `dnu pack`? The former should read your `.nuspec` file.

Comment: Further experimentation found that the package ID appears to be dictated by the folder name that the project lives in. We utilized that, which allows us to use the `dnu pack` command as Microsoft intends for ASP.NET 5.